# c# filenotfoundexception on webbrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, browser

```
if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.IndexOf("Page: 1") != -1)
```

on the above line i am getting this exception

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException was
>   unhandled   Message="The system cannot
>   find the file specified. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80070002)"
>   Source="System.Windows.Forms"
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IPersistStreamInit.Save(IStream
>   pstm, Boolean fClearDirty)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.get_DocumentStream()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.get_DocumentText()
>          at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.GenerateETGWorklists()
>   in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\GenerateWorklists\GenerateWorklists\Form1.cs:line
>   603
>          at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.btnProcess_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents
>   and Settings\agordon\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\GenerateWorklists\GenerateWorklists\Form1.cs:line
>   55
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs
>   mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&
>   m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&
>   m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&
>   m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&
>   m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&
>   m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr
>   lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&
>   msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32
>   pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form
>   mainForm)
>          at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main()
>   in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\GenerateWorklists\GenerateWorklists\Program.cs:line
>   18
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:

what is the meaning of this? i did not get this error yesterday and getting it today. the webpage opens no problem and the text  `Page: 1` is definitely there.

here is a similar issue also without solution
http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/657812-webbrowser-documenttext-getting-problem

Comment: What is the `WebBrowser` displaying?

Comment: you need to check that the file is still in the place that your code is calling it from, that no other process has that file in use and that the privelages still allow this writing and reading of files

Comment: @daniel there's no file yet. it gets it from the webpage

Comment: @JOE, Are you sure you have IE installed with all its core files and dlls?

Comment: @dead this was working yesterday fine

Comment: its a known problem http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/657812-webbrowser-documenttext-getting-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known bug and microsoft doesn't do anything about it for vs2008 at least. here's a fix:

```
String lastsource = ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)(((webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument)))).documentElement.innerHTML;
            webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true);
            webBrowser1.Document.Write(lastsource);
```

now we can access `DocumentText` with no problems

dont forget to import `mshtml` as a reference

Answer (score 0):

Try `webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText`.

Comment: What message and stack trace?

Comment: this was working fine yesterday, the webbrowser is displaying a webpage

Answer (score 0):

I too found it strange that the web browser control was throwing an exception related to file access, when I was loading a page from the web.

When looking into this, I noticed something strange:
This error is far less common when the temporary internet files have recently been cleared.

I modified my application so that it clears the temporary internet files automatically when the application starts, which was enough to resolve 90% of these errors.

My code for cleaning the temporary internet files is below... I don't think this will work on all operating systems - there may be a better way - but this suits my needs because it works on Server 2008.

(my code is in vb.net, but the c# version shouldn't be too hard to figure out.)

```
        'start cleaning the temporary internet files
        Dim clearFilesProcess As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255")

        'wait for the temporary internet files to be deleted
        While Not (clearFilesProcess.HasExited)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
        End While
```